# Parsing txt files in cpp

Tags: c++, file, parsing, txt

I am trying to parse a txt file to get information and create an object with in c++.

Here is an example of few lines that this file contains :

```
Angelic Page,1,1,1,creature,nothing;
Auramancer,2,2,2,creature, nothing;
Dauntless Cathar,2,3,2,nothing;
Fencing Ace,1,1,1,nothing;
Ace aux poings ardents,3,5,5,Human,nothing;
Roronoa Zoro,5,7,7,Demon,nothing;
```

I want to create an object Card with those information :

```
Carte::Carte(std::string name, int cost, int pv, int attack, std::string type, std::string capacity)
{
    std::cout << "\tCreation d'une carte\n\n" << std::endl;
    this->m_name = name;
    this->m_cost = cost;
    this->m_pv = pv;
    this->m_strength = attack;
    this->m_type = type;
    this->m_capacity = capacity;
}
```

Here what i tried :

```
std::vector<Carte> Carte::generateCard(std::string nomFichier)
{
    std::string txtCard;

    std::ifstream readFile(nomFichier);

    std::vector<std::string> cardVec;

    while (std::getline(readFile, txtCard, ';')) {
        cardVec.push_back(txtCard);
    }

    readFile.close();

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vecVecCard;

    for (std::string s : cardVec) {
        std::istringstream stream;
        std::vector<std::string> vecCard;
        stream.str(s);

        for (std::string line; std::getline(stream, line, ','); ) {
            vecCard.push_back(line);
        }
        vecVecCard.push_back(vecCard);
    } 
    
    std::vector<Carte> finalVectorCard;
    
    for (std::vector<std::string> v : vecVecCard) {
        std::string tabTemp[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            tabTemp[i] = v.at(i);
        }
        
        try {
            Carte(tabTemp[0], std::stoi(tabTemp[1]), std::stoi(tabTemp[2]), std::stoi(tabTemp[3]), tabTemp[4], tabTemp[5]);
            finalVectorCard.push_back(c);
        }
        catch (std::invalid_argument const& e) {
            std::cout << "Bad input: std::invalid_argument thrown" << std::endl;
        }
        catch (std::out_of_range const& e) {
            std::cout << "Integer overflow: std::out_of_range thrown" << std::endl;
        }
        
    }

    return finalVectorCard;
```

My logic was :

- first : parse with delimited char ';' --> return a vector with a string like '
  Auramancer,2,2,2,creature, nothing'
- second : parse with delimited char ',' --> return a vector of vector
- create an object with and store it in a vector and return this vector.

This is not working.
When I create a Card, it is getting destroyed immediately. I am a bit lost.

Comment: If you are in control of the format of the text file, it would be a lot easier to make it something more "machine readable." You currently have two different delimeters, the comma and semicolon. That's creating unnecessary work.

Comment: @sweenish i do have the control ! but how to differentiate a simple delimitation between two words and between two different objects? That's why I put semicolons

Comment: It seems like every object always has the same number of fields. That's a good start.

Comment: FYI, you only need the `this->` syntax when method parameters have the same name as member variables.  Try removing the `this->` text in your constructor and see what happens.  Fewer typing means less chances of typo errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `Carte` is destroyed because he when out of scope just after [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

```cpp
for (/*...*/) {
    Carte c = Carte(tabTemp[0], std::stoi(tabTemp[1]), std::stoi(tabTemp[2]),
        std::stoi(tabTemp[3]), tabTemp[4], tabTemp[5]);
    finalVectorCard.push_back(c);
}
// out of scope
```

**Why?**

At every iteration of your `for` loop, `c` is destroyed because the programme don't need it anymore.

**How to fix**

You have 2 options:

- [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back): construct the `Carte` directly in your `std::vector<Card>`
- [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move): move the actual memory used by `c` into your `std::vector`

```cpp
// emplace_back implementation:
finalVectorCard.emplace_back(tabTemp[0], std::stoi(tabTemp[1]),
    std::stoi(tabTemp[2]), std::stoi(tabTemp[3]), tabTemp[4], tabTemp[5]));

// std::move implementation:
Carte c = Carte(tabTemp[0], std::stoi(tabTemp[1]), std::stoi(tabTemp[2]), std::stoi(tabTemp[3]), tabTemp[4], tabTemp[5]);
finalVectorCard.push_back(std::move(c));
```